# Store unsigned int (uint8, 16, 32) in variable

Tags: c++, uint8t

I would like to store an uint8_t (could change to uint_16 or 32 too) with their formatting in a string. I need to format them as hex, and want to store them along with their formatting.
I have something like this (just the core):

```
uint8_t telegramData[];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(telegram); i++)
{
  printf("Uint8_t: %02X", telegramData[i]);
}
```

example output: Uint8_t: C8 4A 00 0D

Instead of printing out should store, but with correct formatting. 
Best would be if I had result as example: string str = "C8 4A 00 0D"
Is there any method for this? Really thanks in advance!

**EDITED**

Hello again,
seems like i found out.
I am using C++, sorry I think made tags mistake.I am using g++ compiler.
Telegram is not relevant that much (yes it has proper size, just didnt note before here- "core code").
Used sprintf finally and this seems like to be a solution for me (again just core, because would take too much to explain every detail):
Please don't bite my head off, I am not best with coding.

```
uint8_t telegram;    
char *tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(telegram));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(telegram); i++)
    {
      sprintf (tmp + strlen(tmp), " %02X", telegram[i]);
    }
    printf ("Uint8_t: %s",tmp);
```

Output result: Uint8_t: C8 4A 00 0D
I know it is not best solution, but most close what I need.
And now it is also stored in tmp, so can use later too, not just printing out once. Thats why needed.

**EDITED**

Some better version:

```
uint8_t telegram;    
char *tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(telegram));
int test = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(telegram); i++)
{
   test += sprintf (tmp + test, " %02X", telegram[i]);
}
printf ("Uint8_t: %s",tmp);
```

Comment: Your tags made no sense - also not sure if you wanted C/C++ so added both!

Comment: What is `telegram`? And when you define `telegramData` in your actual program, do you set an array size?

Comment: As formatting is about presentation and not about storage, why do you need to do this? What am I missing?

Comment: @Moo-Juice Questions shan't be tagged with both C and C++. And this is definitely not C++.

Comment: @H2CO3:  Just because it's not your preferred style doesn't mean SophieH isn't using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @JohnDibling It has nothing to do with preferred style -- one does not use `snprintf()` in C++. Also, C code should not be compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @H2CO3, at the time I edited I didn't know and was hoping the OP would come back with what they were using and I could remove one.  And whilst you are correct - Unfortunately I know plenty of people using C++ and using `printf` and other non-STL functionality.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Yup, and that's exactly what should not be done (and because it is the wrong approach, I was nice enough to assume that OP didn't follow it.)

Comment: @H2CO3:  SophieH was using `printf`, not `snprintf`.  `printf` is in the C++ Standard Library.  It is completely possible to write valid C++ code using `printf` and compile that code with no errors using a C++ compiler.  Only Sophie knows which compiler they are using.  If they come back and say they are using C++, a good answer would advise them not to use `sprintf` but that doesn't mean the question isn't a C++ question.

Comment: @JohnDibling Yes, it's in the C++ standard library. Yes, it is possible to do what you described. It is generally **wrong,** though, and again, I assumed that OP did **not** do that. Following your reasoning, every single person on Earth could be put in jail for murder, because "it is possible to kill a human". But we don't do that, do we?

Comment: @H2CO3:  Argument irrelevant.  Why would you assume in *this* case that a previously unknown SO poster is not doing something in C++ that is considered generally wrong?  I know you don't always do that.  I have read many answers from you where you advise someone that their original assumptions were incorrect and go on to provide a great explanation of what the *right* thing to do is.

Comment: `char *tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(telegram));` is insufficient.,

Comment: If i see this, it could be okay i think http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/

Comment: @SophieH:  Please don't use cplusplus.com as a reference -- it's full of innacuracies and bad advice.  Better would be cppreference.com

Comment: `%02X` Please note that you need 2 bytes per one uint_8.

Comment: @John Dibling. Okay will keep it mind, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), it's a library standard function for producing strings, very much like `printf()` except instead of printing also printing the resulting string, it's just created in memory.

Comment: Yes did that before, and worked out. Thanks all of you!

Answer (score 2):

Your original question did not include a language tag, so it's unclear if you are programming in C or C++.  The two are separate languages, and the best answers will be different for each language.

Although C++ shares a common ancestry with C, and `sprintf` is indeed part of the C++ Standard Library, if you're programming in C++ you probably should not be using `sprintf` or it's related functions.  This family of functions is decidedly type-unsafe.

There are many type-safe ways to do this in C++, but a good place to start is using the C++ streams along with their manipulators:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << telegramData[i];
std::string s = ss.str();
```

There are also type-safe alternatives in the Boost library which share a similar syntax to `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

for C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define uint_join(p, a, ch) do{\
    size_t type_size = sizeof(*a), size = sizeof(a)/type_size;\
    size_t i, len = 0;\
    p = malloc(size * (type_size * 2 + 1));\
    if(p)\
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){\
        switch(type_size){\
        case 1:\
            len += sprintf(p+len, (i < size -1 ? "%0*" PRIX8 "%c" : "%0*" PRIX8), type_size*2, a[i], ch);\
            break;\
        case 2:\
            len += sprintf(p+len, (i < size -1 ? "%0*" PRIX16 "%c" : "%0*" PRIX16), type_size*2, a[i], ch);\
            break;\
        case 4:\
            len += sprintf(p+len, (i < size -1 ? "%0*" PRIX32 "%c" : "%0*" PRIX32), type_size*2, a[i], ch);\
            break;\
        case 8:\
            len += sprintf(p+len, (i < size -1 ? "%0*" PRIX64 "%c" : "%0*" PRIX64), type_size*2, a[i], ch);\
            break;\
        }\
    }\
}while(0)

int main (void){
    uint8_t telegramData[] = { 0xC8, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x0D};
    char *tmp;
    uint_join(tmp, telegramData, ' ');
    printf ("Uint8_t: %s\n", tmp);
    free(tmp);
    return 0;
}
```